# Wait before executing a command (Selenium Webdriver)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, wait

I'm using java in Eclipse - Selenium Webdriver and I need to find a kind of waiting to apply until a command can be successfully executed. I don't want to set myself a specific amount of time like Thread.sleep(), as I need the command to be executed as soon as the page loaded properly. 
I am using until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated()) for page to be loaded and .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable()) when the element can be clicked but I didn't find any proper command to use before sending keys or performing another action than click.

Answer (score 0):

List of methods for class ExpectedConditions we can see [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) 
Example, 
until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected())
until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfAllElements())